# Inline keyboard Markup C# проблема с созданием кнопок в телеграм боте

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, inline

Есть такой код создания кнопок

```
var keyboard = new Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.InlineKeyboardMarkup(new Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.InlineKeyboardButton[][]
                                    {new [] {
                                             new Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.InlineKeyboardButton("Текст для первой кнопки","callback1"),
                                             new Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.InlineKeyboardButton("Текст второй кнопки","callback2"),
                                             },
                                   });
```

Ошибка такая:
'InlineKeyboardButton" не содержит конструктор, который принимает аргументы 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте статический метод 
  Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Текст для первой кнопки","callback1")

Comment: почему-то пишет, что не существует такого типа в типе InlineKeyboardButton, хотя я посмотрел в библиотеку, и он там есть мб я что-то не так подключаю?

Comment: это метод: без new

Comment: спасибо помогло!)

Comment: да на здоровье...

Comment: @yungstepik, если ответ вам помог, отметьте его галочкой, и автору ответа приятно, вопрос не будет висеть в списке не отвеченных, и другим посетителям видно что именно из предложенного вам помогло если ответов больше одного.